# Would I be taxed on a long term currency exchange?

Tags: united-states, taxes, foreign-exchange, usd-us-dollar, cad-canadian-dollar

Recently, USD has been doing really well. I've been considering moving a bunch of money into CAD, to use when I visit there or if I ever move back in the future.

It seems likely to me that by the time I get around to spending it, the CAD would be worth more than the USD I exchanged for it (the entire point of this exercise).

Would I have to pay some kind of capital gains tax? And if so, when?

Also, is there any reason this is a terrible idea?

Comment: I wouldn't bet on USD/CAD moving in any particular direction, myself; I see no way to predict what direction things will move. On the other hand, I know a fair number of folks close to the border who maintain accounts in both currencies so they can deposit or pay without unreasonable conversion fees.

Comment: Please use a country tag when asking a tax question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I have to pay some kind of capital gains tax? And if so, when?

Converting Tax paid USD into CAD is not a taxable event. A taxable even will occur if you convert back the CAD into USD. If you receive interest on the CAD then the interest is also a taxable event.

> Also, is there any reason this is a terrible idea?

That will only be known in future. Its like predicting that in future this will turn out to be advantageous, however it may turn out the other way.

Comment: So theoretically, is anything stopping you from using this as tax free speculation? Just that you can't convert it back to the original currency?

Answer (score 2):

If you are exchanging money for travel then you should not have to pay any capital gains on any exchange that is in your favour. Exchanging currency for travel is different from trading currencies for an attempt at making profits.